# Do NPCs get free attacks only on total Bullet Time failure or also on partial failure?

Tags: combat, ghost-ops

I have the original version of Ghost Ops (which uses Fudge dice), not the Savage Worlds version or the OSR version. This question is about that original version, but if you think the rules in one of the other versions can throw some light on this, please chip in.

On page 132 of the core rulebook there is an example of a failed Bullet Time action. The PC was attempting to shoot 3 NPCs in the head, and needed an 8 but only got a 6.

The book then has some more rules:

> The Handler can decide that the Operator succeeded in some of the attempt. Maybe they barged the door and managed to get 2 of the attempted headshots off but missed the third.
> Failing a Bullet Time event places the Operator as prone for 1 round, allowing any Tangos free attacks. Deciding to attempt Bullet Time is risky but can be ultimately rewarding.

So, if the GM has said the failed roll can be partial success (hit 2 of the NPCs) and partial failure (miss the 3rd NPC), which of these applies?

1. It still counts as a normal fail - the PC is prone and subject to a free attack by all three NPCs (assuming the two he shot aren’t dead or disabled).
2. It still counts as a ‘reduced’ fail  - the PC is prone but only the
   third NPC, who was not hit, gets a free attack.
3. It counts as a success – the PC is not prone and the NPC/s don’t get free attacks.
4. The GM decides on a case by case basis.

I’m hoping there is clarification for this question in one of the expansions, or in an updated version of the pdf (I only have a print copy). I’ve failed to find any errata on the internet.